# Why does typing a post in the Quick Draft or comments, eliminate double spaces?

Tags: draft

I'm personally a fan of using two spaces after periods, in order to improve readability of my material.  But lately I've been using the Quick Draft feature in the dashboard, to jot things down, and then I edit them later into final posts.

I've noticed in every case, that when I save a post created this way, all my careful double spaces are converted to single spaces.  This does not happen if I use the standard New Post feature.  Only when created from a Quick Draft.

This appears to happen for comments too.  Any comment (or comment reply) left that uses two spaces after periods, will be converted to single spaces upon saving.  The spaces are actually modified in the comment source.

Anyone know why this is and if it's a bug?

Comment: Are the spaces there if you view the page _source_? HTML rendering engines collapse multiple spaces into a single space.

Comment: No they are gone.  There is only a single space after every period in the HTML editor.  I forgot to add in the question, that if I go into the full WP editor and change the content to have two spaces instead and update the post, then it will have two spaces as expected.  This is just an issue with the version created by Quick Draft.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing happens in comments.  All double spaces are turned into single spaces in the source.  Can someone please confirm or refute this?