# Emoticons not working on my site

Tags: images

I've always understood WP to have built-in emoticon support.  I have them enabled in the settings, but they just don't do anything.  Here is an example post that contains one at the end of the post, [a wink...](http://iamsoylent.com/reviews/small-smoothie-for-one-coming-up/)

Is there a theme issue here?  It's the Bushwick theme.

Comment: Check if emoticons settings are turned on off at `Settings > Writings > Convert emoticons like :-) and :-P to graphics on display`

Comment: As stated in the question, they are already enabled.

Comment: Then next step is to try disabling all plugins. If still doesn't work, try switching to `twenty fourteen` theme.

Comment: No change in either case.

Comment: Just tested on 3.9.1, and it's working!

Comment: That's great & all but I'm hoping for some suggestions on why it may not be working for me, in my particular case.  It's not plugin related, and not theme specific.  So what the heck is it?  I'm running WP 3.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that WP emoticons don't work if you have a period, one space, and then a smiley.

So this will not work:

`Some text. ;)`

but this will work:

`Some text.  ;)`

Unbelievable.

Comment: Except this-- "don't work if you have a period, one space, and then a smiley"-- isn't true. That isn't the problem. Read the tail end of my answer again.

Comment: I read your question, and I'm telling you that if I do a period, a single space, and a smiley... the smiley does not render.  If I do period, double space, and a smiley, it renders perfectly every time.

Maybe it's not a WP issue per se, but this is what happens for me in my situation and what fixed it.

Comment: What version of WordPress?

Comment: 3.9.1.  And to make things even stranger... now it's working with a single space, double space, or even NO spaces at all between the period and the smiley.  In fact, I can't break it at all anymore.  I'm beginning to wonder if this is a browser issue... I'm running the latest version of Safari as of yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If emoticons are not translating to images, and the feature is enabled as you say, then I suspect that something has removed the [`convert_smilies()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L132) from the [`the_content` hook](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L132), and/or from several other hooks potentially.

I can also break the smilie functionality with a bad filter on `smilies_src`

```
add_filter(
  'smilies_src',
  function($url,$img,$site) {
//  return $url;
  },
  10,3
);
```

Or...

```
add_filter(
  'smilies_src',
  function($url,$img,$site) {
    return 'borken';
  },
  10,3
);
```

If that is the problem, what you will see in the page source is something like this: `<img src="abc" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">`.

Since switching themes doesn't help, it is probably the work of a plugin or a mu-plugin-- "Must Use" Plugins, these work in single sites as well as multisite setups.

The Codex page for Emoticons is worth reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies

If you read that Codex page carefully, you will note that the smilie should be separated by at least a single space on each side to avoid its being confused with other ordinary punctuation. If you check the source of your page your will see: `Soylent smoothies for a while. &nbsp;;)</p>` That is, you don't have the smilie delimited correctly by spaces. You have something inserting `&nbsp;` at the end of each sentence, presumably to created a double-space sentence break. In short, [your fix for this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/145267/21376) seems to have broken your smilies.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and I'll look at those.  It doesn't appear to be plugin related however, since I'm not running MU and I deactivated all plugins, and still the emoticons won't work.

Comment: Well I've looked over the codex, verified my smilies are present, and even added a convert_smilies filter just for good measure - no change.  No smilies at all.  Theme doesn't seem to matter (tried Bushwick and 2014) and plugins don't matter (disabled them all).  I'm at a loss... any other suggestions?

Comment: @JonathanvanClute : See the edit.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a plugin, as I deactivated ALL plugins, change to the 2014 theme, and still... no smiley.

Comment: @JonathanvanClute : See the edit, again. This one got it.

Comment: Found the answer on my own... crazy, see above.

Comment: You're on the right track that it's space related, but in my source code there are no NBSPs at all.  Also a single space on either side, would not work (I verified this) it required a double space before (and no spaces after was fine too)

Comment: Don't look at the PHP source. Look at the generated HTML source. There are no breaking spaces. I copied that example straight from your page.

Comment: I'm looking at the page source in Safari.  No NBSPs anywhere.